# Roundcube Error: Connection to storage server failed

Tags: email, dovecot, webmail

I installed Roundcube on a Debian server running Dovecot, Postfix, mySQL for mail, and postfixadmin.

Then I installed Roundcube.

I have another server with the same configuration.

I can send and receive using IMAP/SMTP with Thunderbird.  But when I connect using the Roundcube client I get the error:

`Connection to storage server failed.`

What process should I use to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roundcube uses IMAP to interact with the mailstore, check that the server running roundcube can connect to the server running IMAP (this is probably localhost)

Possibly the IMAP server is not available on localhost (`::1`) but is on "ipv4 localhost" aka `127.0.0.1`

Comment: This was part of the problem.  I did not have IMAP installed because who uses that?  But there was another problem.  This version of roundcube has a new config file in /var/lib/rouncube/config and the database connection password was not set in there.  Thank you @Jasen